# RUBY: how to resolve circular dependency in constant definitions?

Tags: ruby, constants

```
class A
  X = 9
  Y = B::X
end

class B
  X = 8
  Y = A::X
end
```

I have two classes each defining some constants but requiring constants
from the other as shown above but this gives me an error:

circular.rb:7:in `<class:A>': uninitialized constant A::B (NameError)
 from circular.rb:5:in`'

Is there any way to resolve the error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you split the definition of A into two parts:

```
class A
  X = 9
end

class B
  X = 8
  Y = A::X
end

class A
  Y = B::X
end
```

Comment: Just to be clear: the problem here, as shown by the solution by sepp2k, is not that you have a circular dependency, but that you're trying to use a constant before it's defined. You'll get the same effect even without a circular reference. Splitting up the class definitions solves the problem because it makes sure all the constants are defined before they're used.