# Two classes that use constants of each other

Tags: ruby

I have classes `A` and `B`, each of which needs some constant from the other. When I do this:

```
class A
  puts B::CONSTANT
  CONSTANT = "A constant"
end

class B
  puts A::CONSTANT
  CONSTANT = "B constant"
end
```

then I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant B::CONSTANT
```

A circular dependency exists, as each class needs the other class to be loaded first. What is the solution for such case?

**Edit**

In my original case there was no circular dependency, but I had a class A that uses a constant from another class B, however A was loaded before B so an exception was thrown, then I forced the load of B before A, but then I thought: what will I do if I have circular dependency?

Comment: What's the practical application of this? One solution is to remove circular dependency.

Comment: I think that you're asking the same question of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354427/ruby-how-to-resolve-circular-dependency-in-constant-definitions

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you have to have only one class body for each class, and have the contents in that order. Simply do:

```
class A
  CONSTANT = "A constant"
end

class B
  CONSTANT = "B constant"
end

class A
  puts B::CONSTANT
end

class B
  puts A::CONSTANT
end
```